# getting stored numbers using Bit Shifting in Java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble trying to reverse engineer this section of code; I need to be able to get x, y, z from l would anyone be able to point me in the right direction. Thanks

```
 int l = ((X << 20) + (Y << 19) + Z);
```

The ranges are as follows

```
X = 0 - 4095
Y = 0 - 1
Z = 0 - 384,794
```

Comment: What are the ranges on those three variables? If they can all be *any* integer, then it's impossible since the forward function is non-injective. If they're all either 0 or 1, it's manageable.

Comment: Simple example proving that this is impossible without a range: (X: 0, Y: 10, Z: 0) is the same as (X: 0, Y: 0, Z: 5242880)

Comment: The ranges are as follows Z would be 0  to 384,794,  x  is 0 - 4095 and y is either 1 or 0

Answer (score 3):

X being 0-4095 = 12 bits

Y being 0-1 = 1 bit

Z being 0-384794 = 19 bits

Java integers are 32 bit, so starting from 0:

`int l = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`

**+ X << 20** = the value of X, moved 20 places to the right. So:

`int l = XXXX XXXX XXXX 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`

**+ Y << 19** = the value of Y, moved 19 places to the right. So:

`int l = XXXX XXXX XXXX Y000 0000 0000 0000 0000`

**+ Z** = the value of Z, moved 0 places. So:

`int l = XXXX XXXX XXXX YZZZ ZZZZ ZZZZ ZZZZ ZZZZ`

Since no bits are ever overwritten, we can recover them:

```java
int x = l >> 20 & 0xFFF;   //reverse the shifting (by 20), then isolate the X bits (0xFFF = 12 bits set to 1, equal to 4095)
int y = l >> 19 & 0x1;     //reverse the shifting (by 19), then isolate the Y bit (0x1 = 1 bit set to 1, equal to 1)
int z = l & 0x7FFFF;       //no shifting to reverse, but we still isolate the Z bits (0x7FFFF = 19 bits set to 1, equal to 524287)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I can see where I was going wrong now. I wasn't isolating the bits on retrieval.

Comment: Lowercase L is a terrible name for a variable. Also, you don't need to isolate the bits of `x` since all the other bits have been shifted out.

Comment: @DavidConrad a lowercase L was the original variable name from the question, so I've just followed that. And while it's true you don't have to isolate the bits of X, it's clearer to see what's going on when you do, in my opinion anyways.

Comment: Fair enough. My comment was as much for OP as it was in relation to your answer.